# error on using rails_apps_composer w/ twitter-bootstrap less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a new app using rails_apps_composer.
What went well some weeks ago doesn't work anymore.

I'm using config vars:

```
:frontend: bootstrap
:bootstrap: less
```

and for now composer breaks with several error messages as of

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@testapp/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `less' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fbb714356c8> (NoMethodError)
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@testapp/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.6/lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine.rb:15:in `block in <class:Engine>'
```

When I use *sass*, it works. However, I have to use *less*.

Gems are up to date:

```
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.6)
less (2.2.2)
```

I also tried to add *less* explicitly as an additional gem with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a missing gem: less-rails.

Somehow it must have been removed from the composer in one of the last commits.

Solution:

- Adding "less-rails" as additional gem makes it work again.

To be done: put it (back?) to rails_apps_composer.